# Pushing data to angularjs externally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems that angularjs can only interact with data that each module has internally, but there's no way for any external javascript to change the data or access a service of angularjs.

For example, if I have some non-angularjs code and an angularjs module running side by side, and the non-angularjs code needs to update some data that angularjs uses (such as by calling a service method), is there a way to do that?

Another example, lets say I'm using Comet and pushing notifications from the server. So e.g, if the user receives a new message, I want to be able to push a notification of that from the server (e.g sending some javascript code via a http-chunk response, and having that code be executed). How could I pass on these notifications to my angular services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach angular scope trough non-angular js with something like this:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('page-data')).scope().$apply(
    function(scope)
    {
        scope.yourScopeMethod( argument1, argument2, ... );
    });
```

Where:

```
document.getElementById('page-data')
```

is the html element containing your angular view.

Comment: what will be `scope.yourMethod` in this case? what if i need to call a particular angularjs service from non-angular js?

Comment: scope.yourMethod would be any method defined in your scope. For example, you can define a method name "callServiceA" and then use scope.callServiceA() to call it from nonangular js, as shown in my first post.

Comment: How/where would I define `scope.callServiceA`? if you can provide a more complete example i could understand it better..